# New line character not working in php

Tags: php, fwrite, plaintext

I am creating a log file for all api call in my application which is written in php (Symfony).
While creating log file I have used "\n" as new line characters but it's not working.

```
my code is -
    $log = "\n Account: ".$Account."---ID: ".$ID;
    $log .= "\n Params: ".$params."\n";
    $log .= "\n response: ".$response."\n";
```

It gives me out put in one line, I also tried "\r\n" and "PHP_EOL" but it doesn't works.

How can I able to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you look at the output in the browser ?

Comment: you try use `<br>` instead of `\n`.

Comment: have you tried with PHP_EOL? $log=PHP_EOL.$Account.PHP_EOL;

Comment: If you try to read \n in notepad (WIndows) it may not give the desired result (no new lines) \r\n should... Linux doesn't care much, but may show ^M in vi... But I fail to see what you are writing to and how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP New Line will not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031597/php-new-line-will-not-work)

Comment: If you run it on linux and view the file in windows, the line endings will be different. Use something better than Notepad, like Notepad++ or PhpStorm. - This also depends on your code to write the file - do you strip anything?

Comment: Refer my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace `\n` with `<br>`, but without space in the brackets

Answer (score 1):

Below should work. And I am using this on my all projects to find the error

```
$contents = file_get_contents('text.txt'); // TO LOAD THE EXISTING CONTENTS OF ERROR LOG FILE
    $contents .= PHP_EOL."\n Account: ".$Account."---ID: ".$ID; // CONCAT. ACCOUNT NUMBER
    $contents .= PHP_EOL."\n Params: ".$params."\n"; // CONCAT. PARAMS
    $contents .= PHP_EOL."\n response: ".$response."\n"; // CONCAT. RESPONSE
    file_put_contents('text.txt', $contents, FILE_APPEND); // WRITING ENIRE LOG BACK INTO LOG FILE
```